# How to understand "for" in the sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> The baby is named ***for*** his grandfather.

I know that "to be named for someone means to be given the same name as them". But I can't figure out the meaning of "for".

Comment: The more common expression is "the child was named **after** his grandfather. "For" can be read as "for [his grandfather's sake]".

Comment: @oerkelens: If "for" can be read as "for [his grandfather's sake", why it can "'s sake"  be omitted?

Comment: That is called language. Speakers of English will understand that meaning without the word being replaced by its appropriate dictionary definition. When I say "I eat bread", it can be understood as "I eat a baked product made of ground grain, water and yeast", but I will usually not say that :)

Comment: @oerkelens: So can I say :"The child was named because of his grandfather"?

Comment: You could. But it would not make much sense. To be someone's namesake is idiomatic and means you are named X because someone else was named X. In general, go for "name _after_", it is the more common construct anyway :)

Comment: @oerkelens Good question, good answer. Book it, Danno.

Answer (score 1):

The more common expression is "the child was named *after* his grandfather.

However, you can use *for*. In that case, *for* can be read as "for [his grandfather's sake]".

The reason that [his grandfather's sake] can be omitted, is because of how speakers use and understand language: speakers of English will understand the meaning without the word being replaced by its appropriate dictionary definition.
When I say "I eat bread", it can be understood as "I eat a baked product made of ground grain, water and yeast", but I will usually not say that :)

As for "The child was named because of his grandfather", you could say that. But it would not make much sense. It would mean that somehow the grandfather was the cause of the child being given a name, any name. Normally, a child will be given a name anyway, without a grandfather having to cause that.

To be someone's namesake is idiomatic and means you are named X because someone else was named X. In general, go for "name after", it is the more common construct.